# Two-legged OAuth Yahoo PHP example

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo-api, two-legged

I try to make private API requests for Yahoo. I used the code below but it does not work. It always returns the message 'invalid sig'.
Can you help me with a Two-legged OAuth Yahoo PHP example that works?

Thank you very much.

```
<?php // a super-stripped down 2-leg oauth server/client example

//http://oauth.net/code/
//http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth.php
require 'oauth.php';

$key = 'key';
$secret = 'secret';
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

if ($_GET['server']) {
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $sig = $_GET['oauth_signature'];
    $req = new OAuthRequest($method, $uri);
    // token is null because we're doing 2-leg
    $valid = $sig_method->check_signature($req, $consumer, null, $sig);
    if (!$valid) {
        die('invalid sig');
    }
    echo 'orale!';
}
else {
    // call this file
    $api_endpoint = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    // handle request in 'server' block above
    $parameters = array(
            'server' => 'true');

    // use oauth lib to sign request
    $req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, "GET", $api_endpoint, $parameters);
    $sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, null); // note: double entry of token

    // get data using signed url
    $ch = curl_init($req->to_url());
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: This might help you, at least on the workflow side: http://nullinfo.wordpress.com/oauth-yahoo/

Comment: It's a good example, but it need to get the user authorization for my application. How can I make a Two-legged OAuth flow (no user authorization)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you generate the signature according to the Yahoo specification [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html#oauth-sign-hmac)?
Or you can use plaintext signature as described [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-sign-plaintext.html).